# How I can download mlt module glaxnimate?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to download mlt module   glaxnimate for **Kdenlive** when I run Kdenlive [it show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDWZO.png) I am trying download it from [github](https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/releases) but unable to get execute
after I run

```
  git clone https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/releases/download/v7.8.0/mlt- 
7.8.0.tar.gz
Cloning into 'mlt-7.8.0.tar.gz'...
remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/releases/download/v7.8.0/mlt- 
7.8.0.tar.gz/' not found
```

when I try to add through clone
my Ubuntu version

```
Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
Description:  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:   22.04
Codename:  jammy
```

hardware

```
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
Intel CPU: Intel i5-8250U (8) @ 3.400GHz 
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620 
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 
530/535 / 620/625 Mobile
```

Kdenlive is 22.08.1

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: A must read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolve it by Download AppImage file of **kdenlive**

First uninstall **kdenlive**
after that run

```
sudo apt install libfuse2
```

it is required to run AppImage file then Download The **Kdenlive AppImage**
after that right click on it
In the next screen, go to the Permissions tab and check the box that says “Allow executing file as program”
double click on it it will run

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sarthak's answer, if you try installing it and it says it's installed, you'll need to reinstall it with the following command.

`sudo apt reinstall libfuse2`

Not sure what triggers needed to be reprocessed, but KDEnlive opens just fine after that.